# If $\hat{U}$ is unitary: $f(\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{A}\hat{U}) = \hat{U}^\dagger f(\hat{A})\hat{U}$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I'm trying to prove the statement in the title, where $\hat{U}$ is a unitary operator. If I expand the function $f$:
\begin{align}
f(\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{A}\hat{U}) &=\sum_k f_k (\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{A}\hat{U})^k\\
&=\sum_k f_k\hat{U}^{\dagger k}\hat{A}^k\hat{U}^k.
\end{align}

I would like to use the fact that $\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{U} = 1$ here to eliminate the $k$ power from the $U$ operator in the summation. I miss that step, since I would get

$$\sum_k f_k\hat{U}^{\dagger k}\hat{A}^k\hat{U}^k = \sum_k f_k\hat{U}^{\dagger}\hat{A}^k\hat{U} =\hat{U}^{\dagger}\left[\sum_k f_k\hat{A}^k\right]\hat{U} = \hat{U}^{\dagger}f(\hat{A})\hat{U}.$$

I don't know how to accomplish that step. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the second line of your equation : you have
$$(\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{A}\hat{U})^k\neq (\hat{U}^\dagger )^k\hat{A}^k\hat{U}^k,$$
since matrix multiplication is not commutative. Instead, you have
$$(\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{A}\hat{U})^k = (\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{A}\hat{U})\cdot(\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{A}\hat{U}) \cdots(\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{A}\hat{U})=\hat{U}^\dagger\hat{A}^k\hat{U},$$
where the second equality comes from the fact that $\hat{U}\cdot \hat{U}^\dagger=1$. From there you can finish the proof.

Comment: I should have some rest by now haha. Thanks.